# ¿Cómo puedo colocar un número random generado por una función en un label en php?

Tags: php, html

tengo un problema el cual trata de que debo generar un número aleatorio y transformarlo a mes, la función para generar números aleatorio de un rango de 1 a 12 lo he hecho en php, pero quiero encontrar la forma de que ese resultado lo llame a través de un botón y luego almacenarlo en un label para luego con otro botón lo imprima convertido a mes, gracias por ver.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Ejercicio 2</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <h2>Ejercicio 2</h2>
  <h4>Convertir un número en mes</h4>
  <hr>
<table width=400 >
    <tr>
        <td width=200>
            <b>Número a convertir</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="txtN1" size="10" maxlenght="3" value="<?php  echo $vrandom;?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="BRandom" value="Número Random">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="BRandom" value="Enviar">
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>

  <? php
    function random(){
      $vrandom=rand(1,12);
    return $vrandom;
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Si quieres usar la función que tienes en **PHP** para generar el aleatorio tendrías que lanzar con el botón una llamada **AJAX** desde **Javascript** a dicha función. Creo que eso es bastante innecesario pudiendo hacer una función que haga lo mismo en **JS** y así te evitas lanzar llamadas al servidor para algo que puedes resolver directamente en el **front**.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, lo intentaré, recién estoy empezando en lo que es programación web y me están enseñando el lenguaje php y html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esta seria la respuesta segun la manera en la que trabajas tu codigo:

```
<?php
    function random(){
      $vrandom=rand(1,12);
    return $vrandom;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Ejercicio 2</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <h2>Ejercicio 2</h2>
  <h4>Convertir un número en mes</h4>
  <hr>
<table width=400 >
    <tr>
        <td width=200>
            <b>Número a convertir</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="txtN1" size="10" maxlenght="3" value="<?php  echo random();?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="BRandom" value="Número Random">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="BRandom" value="Enviar">
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

---

Pero yo te recomendaria que manejes tus archivos php esta manera:

```
<?php

$vrandom=rand(1,12);

$page='
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Ejercicio 2</h2>
<h4>Convertir un número en mes</h4>
<hr>
<table width=400 >
  <tr>
      <td width=200>
          <b>Número a convertir</b>
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" name="txtN1" size="10" maxlenght="3" value="'.$vrandom.'">
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="submit" name="BRandom" value="Número Random">
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="submit" name="BRandom" value="Enviar">
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

echo $page;

?>
```

Una Ventaja es que es muchísimo mas fácil depurar, renderizar y realizar logica, por lo generar no se recomienda combinar los dos lenguaje (php y html) aunque por lo que veo muchas personas lo hacen.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.